# How to solve the apparent incompatibility between longtblr from the tabularray package and the parskip package?

Tags: tables, spacing, paragraphs, parskip, tabularray

In my text I need the spacing between paragraphs to be one `\baselineskip`, so I am using the `parskip` package with the `skip=\baselineskip` option. My text also has several long tables, which I am making with the `longtblr` environment from the `tabularray` package. The problem between both packages is in the `notes` and `remarks` that appear at the bottom of the table, because the spacing between them seems to be a paragraph skip. Could someone help me?

## Table using the `parskip` package and showing the problem

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[skip=\baselineskip]{parskip}    
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[%
caption={The caption},
label={TAB:Table},
remark{first}={First line},
remark{second}={Second line}
]{%
colspec={X[l,m]},
rowhead = 1
}
\hline
Head \\
\hline
\blindtext \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Table without using the `parskip` package

This is the expected result of the table, but I lose the paragraph spacing I need in my text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularray}
%\usepackage[skip=\baselineskip]{parskip} <- Removed    
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[%
caption={The caption},
label={TAB:Table},
remark{first}={First line},
remark{second}={Second line}
]{%
colspec={X[l,m]},
rowhead = 1
}
\hline
Head \\
\hline
\blindtext \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well there is a paragraph there. You could reset \parskip for the table with `\AddToHook{env/longtblr/begin}{\setlength\parskip{0pt}}`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed in version 2022A (2022-03-01) of `tabularray` package. Now you get the expected result:

[image]